# Get nearby places without using user's access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does Facebook API allow apps to get nearby places/POIs without the need to provide a user's access token, but with only the app's key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, sure does.

`http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dstation%26type%3Dplace%26center%3D37.76%2C-122.427%26distance%3D1000`

Place your app access token in the Access token field, and then click Submit.

Comment: I used https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<app_id>&client_secret=<app_secret> to get the access token for my app, and then try the above query using the access token, it gave me the following error, is there anything wrong? {
  "error": {
    "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 104
  }
}

Comment: Then clearly your oauth is broken.  Try using a token from the explorer tool.  As stated that query consistently returns good results.  Do you have a center and distance you'd like me to run to show that this does work with a valid app access token?

Comment: The query did work fine if I, as Facebook user, is logged in. And the  access token for me is way longer than the access token that I got for my app. Then after I replaced my access token to the app's access token (which is all what I did), the error returns.

Comment: I used "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<my_app_id>&client_secret=<my_app_secret>" in browser to get the access token returned. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: Hey @DMCS, is there anything wrong with the query that I used to get the access token for my app? And also, is it expected to get a short access token for an app?

Comment: Per http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/ your link to get an app token looks fine.  But do two things.  Lint the token and also compare it to one you get from the explorer tool.

Comment: sorry what did you mean 'Lint the token'? the one got from explorer tool (when I logged in) is about 128 characters long, but the one got for my app (when I logged out and provide the app_id and app_secret) is 32 characters long.

Comment: Just lint it, with my app's access token, it correctly returned my appid and app name.

Comment: but still I am getting the same error when using my app's access token for doing the place search that you suggested above. Is there a link or something that can confirm that the place search could be done with app's access token instead of user's? sorry to bother you so much...

Comment: I'm not really sure at all how to help you any further.  I've not had any issue using an app access token on that search.  I've tried a few different apps and all seem to work (I've got around 45 apps to choose from).  Try creating a new app and see if it works any better for you.

Comment: This query still needs a User access token, isn't it? Pardon me if I missed something here.

Comment: Nopes You are correct, it would not need a user access token, rather an app Access token would work.